# Full Change Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

The following graph has vertices with total 183.  There are 183 ways to remove a set of one of more connected vertices so that the remaining vertices are connected.  These 183 sets have distinct totals 1 to 183.  If stacks of coins were on the vertices, any amount of change is in a connected set that leaves a connected set.

[image: full change graph]

Call a graph with this property a *full change graph*.  Complete graph $K_n$ is a full change graph by distributing $2^0 .. 2^{n-1}$ among the vertices.

What other graphs are full change graphs?

Comment: Just to confirm I'm understanding what's going on properly: The line graph on $3$ vertices would be a full change graph with labels $1,2,2$, correct? (More generally, I think $1,2,2,\dots,2$ should be a full change graph for any number of vertices in a line, if I understand the question properly.)

Comment: Do you allow zero or negative labels? I think that would allow for more graphs to be labeled (e.g. the tree on five vertices with one universal vertex can be labeled $(-1,1,2,3,4)$ but cannot be labeled with positive labels).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did this problem come up? And how did you find the example labeling of the wheel graph?

Comment: I used differences between neighboring values in a cyclic difference set, then realized I could add a central value.  Then noticed $K_n$ and decided to ask the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a partial result: If you allow for negative labels, every (labeled) tree on $n$ vertices can be labeled to be a full change graph in exactly $2^{n-1}(n-1)!$ ways.

Call a connected subset of a graph's vertices "biconnected" if its removal leaves the graph connected.

First note that the partitions of a tree into two connected subgraphs are exactly the "slices" by an edge, and in addition we have the removal of every vertex. So, there are exactly $2n-1$ ways to pick a nonempty biconnected set with $n$ vertices.

Label the vertices $V_1,\dots,V_n$, and for each "cut" into $\{S,\ T\backslash S\}$ assign sums at will among $\{1,2,\dots,2n-2\}$ so that the sum assigned to $S$ and the sum assigned to $T\backslash S$ add to $2n-1$. I believe there are $2^{n-1}(n-1)!$ ways to do this.

We will prove by induction on $n$ that each assignment of the sum $s$ over all the vertices (to any integer; here $2n-1$) and sums over the biconnected subsets to any integers so that any complementary biconnected subsets add to $s$ results in exactly one labeling of all the vertices.

The base case of $n=1$ is trivial -- there is exactly one vertex and we are given its label $s$.

For the inductive step, take a leaf $L$. We know its label (as it is a biconnected subset), so it is labeled uniquely. Now, consider $T'=T\backslash L$. The biconnected subsets of $T'$ are exactly that of $T$, except that those that contain $L$ no longer do -- in particular, we know all their sums. So we may apply the inductive hypothesis and relabel.

Edit: It was not originally clear why the sum of $2n-1$ must be assigned to the sum of all the vertices. To prove this, sum up the labels across all the biconnected subsets. On one hand, each vertex is counted exactly $n$ times, so you get $n$ times the sum of the labels of the vertices. On the other,

$$1+2+\dots+(2n-1)=n(2n-1).$$

**Remark.** This is probably not very well written up. Please don't hesitate to comment if something is not clear.

---

Now, if our graph is not a tree, there are no longer $n$ equations in $n$ variables; there are more. So, we expect that in most cases such labelings do not exist. However, they seem to a lot of the time, in the examples of the wheel graph and $K_n$ given in the above post. I'll update this answer if I come up with anything more.

It does, however, seem that the cycle graph $C_n$ has such a labeling. Examples:

$$(1,2,4),(1,2,6,4),(1,3,2,7),(1,3,10,2,5),(1,2,5,4,6,13),(1,2,7,4,12,5)$$

Comment: I don't think $C_7$ has a labeling.  Difference sets.

Comment: @EdPegg I'm not sure I follow. What's a difference set?

Comment: https://www.dmgordon.org/diffset/  with lambda <= 1

Comment: The total cannot be $2n$.  If it is, then $n$ can be picked, which would leave $n$, violating the conditions.  $K_4$-edge is thus not allowed.